# Trigger multiple classes within js funtion

Tags: javascript, animation, slide, effects

so i found this js somewhere, which is working perfectly fine. But how can i add this funtion to a diffrent class without overwriting it? like i want to use the same funtion but for a diffrent object in my html, so that i can use the same effect again just at a diffrent viewpoint and with a diffrent object on my page.

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    myID = document.getElementById("advertisement");

    var myScrollFunc = function () {
        var y = window.scrollY;
        if (y >= 550) {
            myID.className = "advertisement show"
        } else {
            myID.className = "advertisement hide"
        } 
    };

    window.addEventListener("scroll", myScrollFunc);
});
```

i tried to just copy paste it and create a new variable but im a js beginner so had no luck with that

Comment: avoid doing `$(document).scroll(function() {` and `window.addEventListener("scroll"` you only need one, your actually adding an event every time you scroll. Inside your func just [loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration) over an array of selectors

Comment: It's almost always wrong to add an event listener inside another event listener.

Comment: Also, don't use `className = ` this will override any existing classNames. Use instead `classList` and its methods `.add()` `.remove()` `.toggle()`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the jQuery scroll event. Only the inner JavaScript one.
Also, use [classList.toggle("className", force)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) instead:

```js
const elAdvertisement = document.querySelector("#advertisement");

const toggleAdvertisement = () => {
  elAdvertisement.classList.toggle("hide", scrollY < 550);
};

addEventListener("scroll", toggleAdvertisement); // On scroll
toggleAdvertisement(); // On init
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 1000vh; /* just to force scrollbars */
}

#advertisement {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
Scroll down

<div id="advertisement" class="hide">ADVERTISEMENT HERE</div>
```

If you are using jQuery, here's a code sample with that library:

```js
const $advertisement = $("#advertisement");

const toggleAdvertisement = () => {
  $advertisement.toggleClass("hide", scrollY < 550);
};

$(document).on("scroll", toggleAdvertisement); // On scroll
toggleAdvertisement(); // On init
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 1000vh; /* just to force scrollbars */
}

#advertisement {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
Scroll down

<div id="advertisement" class="hide">ADVERTISEMENT HERE</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```